# .Net WPF ViewPort3D display destroyed on NVIDIA RTX A1006/Intel(R) UHD Graphics

Tags: .net, wpf, viewport3d

We develop with Viewport3D a chart looks like this
[image: normal appearence]

It works a long time very well, but this week a cutomer send as following screen shot:
[image: destroyed appearence]

We check already pc. All things new and up to date (Windows 10 22H2, NVIDIA RTX A1006 ...). We try other resolutions. Nothing helps.

Is there anybody there that can give us a suggestion, what we should try.

Comment: WPF uses DirectX 9, so ask the customer to install DirectX 9 and see if this helps: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer IT-Support find a solution: in NVIDIA Control Panel we can set special 3D Settings for grapic card. It looks like that there some options must be set (we only get a picture of settings) We can only see Base profile is changed  and use High-performance NVIDIA processor. In Settings we see that Image Spapenning, Ambient Occlusion, Antalasing FxAA and Antialasing-Transparency was turne off, Anisotropic Filtering and Antialasing Mode is controlled by Application and Antialsing Gamma correction is turned on.
From our view the import point is, that 3D in WPF is controlled by special options in graphic card settings.

Comment: The only relevant (and in hind-sight really obvious) thing you need to do is let your application run on the discrete GPU, the Nvidia one in your case. All the other settings don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Customer IT-Support find a solution:
[image]

Comment: Please do not just post an image as an answer. Add some description to show how the it would help solving the problem.